# Different height div in not displayed in GridView

Tags: html, css, gridview

There is a small problem in displaying `div`s of different height in a gridview; there are some spaces between the `div`s and that looks poor.

How to remove those spaces? Here is my code:

```
<ul>
  <?php
  while($stmt->fetch())
  {
    $time=new DateTime($time);
  ?>
      <li class="linkli">
      <div>
        <a href="page1.php?qid=<?php echo $id?>&title=<?php echo     
str_replace(" ","-",htmlspecialchars($title)); ?>" id="title_link">
        <p id="title"><?php echo $title;?></p>
        <pre><p id="desc"><?php echo substr($desc,0,150);?>...</p>  
        </pre>
        <p id="time"><?php echo $time->format('M j Y g:i A');?></p>
        <p id="tags"><?php echo $category;?></p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Here is my css

```
ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  display:block;
}
.linkli {
  display:inline-block;
  width:300px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:10px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px #BDBDBD;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color:white;
  vertical-align: top;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you send a screen shot?

Comment: Soory but i cannot upload images stackoverflow say i have to earn 10 reputation so can you help me out from my code

Comment: Okay try setting a standard height.

Comment: thats my main problem i dont have to set standard height because every div content is different so there is different height